# what is the best way to have a page with dynamic content?

Tags: php

I have a doubt about what is the best way of make dynamic content in a php page. 
I must do somthing like this:

```
------------------------------
|           Header           |
------------------------------
|      menu    |  Dynamic    |
|              |  content    |
------------------------------
```

I put this code in my index page between the html content.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET["page_content"]))
        include_once 'app/view/'.$_GET["page_content"].'.php';
?>
```

this include some parts of html inside of my index page, this make it "dynamic". 
In the other hand i think in separe headers and footers of the page, and included in the other pages.

I think those solutions will be better, but not sure what is the best aproach.

(I would like resolve this in php, without making a single page application)

Comment: What has layouts to do with PHP?

Comment: But what exactly is your question?

Comment: _" In the other hand i think in separe headers and footers of the page, and included in the other pages."_ .... go with this.

Comment: @Voitcus My question is "What is the best aproach/tecnic for dynamic content?" I explain what i do, and i was serching for more suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways good and bad to make templates and dynamic content. Firstly you should divide your code to Templates, Data handling and Connection between these two.

[Model View Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) is perfect for this.

For your view you can use either pure html + php or template system like **smarty**, **phpsavant** etc. personally I use smarty because it's easy and very powerful.

If you don't want to use MVC, you can create your own system for example with AJAX. 
This system requries from you to create ajax functions after menu items are clicked.

links to visit if you want to do it with client side

- http://deluxe-menu.com/ajax-technology-menu-sample.html
- http://jqueryui.com/tabs/
- http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

the simpliest solution is to use include but for sure you musn't use **$_GET** with include is dangerous better way is to put files in some kind of array and in $_GET has keys to this array for example.

```
$mods = array("music", "download", "main");

if(in_array($_GET['mod'], $mods))
{
   include('mods/'.$_GET['mod'].".php");
}
```

you can also add here some preg_match to like mod should contain only small letters **/[a-z]+/**

The other better solution

```
$mod = intval($_GET['mod'], 0)
$mods = array(1 => "music", 2 => "download", 3=> "main");
if(!$mod) throw new Exception("Bad module");
if(array_key_exists($mod, $mods)) 
   include("mods/".$mods[$mod].".php");
else 
   if(!$mod) throw new Exception("The module does not exists");
```

However, the best solution is to use some kind of framework for example Zend which has already written class to handle this called [Zend View](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.introduction.html)

Answer (score 0):

you should look into templating systems that are used with php. For example `Smarty` and `Zend_Framework` are some of the ways to use templating.